# return rows from 30 days ago in sql tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-convert

I want to fetch up rows of two tables from 30 days ago in sql
but my date column is nvarchar and I cant convert it to date 
I tried several things but But did not receive any result and And always got an error

this is my query and
I send TodayTime parameter from program by @Date to sql

```
[dbo].[Report30Days]
@Date nvarchar(10)
as

select
    coalesce(S.Date,B.Date) Date,
    coalesce(S.TAccount,0) sTAccount,
    coalesce(S.Remaining,0) sRemaining,
    coalesce(B.TAccount,0) bTAccount,
    coalesce(B.Remaining,0) bRemaining
from
    (select
        Date,sum(TAccount) TAccount, sum(Remaining) Remaining
    from SaleInvoices
    where
        DateDiff(day,convert(datetime,@Date,110),convert(datetime,Date,110))<=30
    group by Date) S
    Full Outer Join
    (select
         Date,sum(TAccount) TAccount, sum(Remaining) Remaining
    from BuyInvoices
    where
        DateDiff(day,convert(datetime,@Date,110),convert(datetime,Date,110))<=30
    group by Date ) B
    on
        S.Date=B.Date
```

my problem is here

```
where
        DateDiff(day,convert(datetime,@Date,110),convert(datetime,Date,110))<=30
```

Date Column in Tables and @Date Format => 2017/02/02

After execute this procedure , This error will be displayed :

**The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.**

Please Guide Me

Thank you very much

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting? Also, what is the data type of `Date`?

Comment: Why do you need to pass today's date as parameter to the stored procedure? You can just get the today's date in your SQL script. Also, why do you have to define the parameter type as nvarchar?

Comment: Can you use a less ambiguous date example?  like december 31st ?

Comment: try passing the string as '2017-02-02'

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: DateTime Column in Tables and @Date Format => 2017/02/02
excuse me I'm Beginner and I use from nvarchar becuase that is easier for solar(Shamsi) calender

Comment: `2017/02/02` doesn't tell me which one is the month and which one is the day. Would it be `2017/12/31` or `2017/31/12` ? Or you could just tell us `YYYY/MM/DD` or `YYYY/DD/MM`

Comment: yyyy/mm/dd     2017/02/02

Comment: The whole root of your problem is right here "my date column is nvarchar". When you use the wrong datatype your queries become a LOT more difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@date` should really be a `date` data type instead (or `datetime`, or `datetime2`). Using n/varchar for dates is a bad decision.

```
/* lets make a proper date parameter */
/* @date nvarchar format is  YYYY/MM/DD, replacing / gives us YYYYMMDD 
   which sql server can easily convert to a date    */
declare @ActualDate date;
set @ActualDate = dateadd(day,-30,convert(date,replace(@date,'/','')));

select
    coalesce(S.Date,B.Date) Date,
    coalesce(S.TAccount,0) sTAccount,
    coalesce(S.Remaining,0) sRemaining,
    coalesce(B.TAccount,0) bTAccount,
    coalesce(B.Remaining,0) bRemaining
from
    (select
        Date,sum(TAccount) TAccount, sum(Remaining) Remaining
    from SaleInvoices
    where convert(date,replace(Date,'/','')) => @ActualDate
    group by Date
    ) S
    Full Outer Join
    (select
         Date,sum(TAccount) TAccount, sum(Remaining) Remaining
    from BuyInvoices
    where convert(date,replace(Date,'/','')) => @ActualDate
    group by Date 
    ) B
    on S.Date=B.Date
```

Comment: excuse me , date columns in the tables are nvarchar too
and Still shows an error on execute

Comment: @MPersia updated... Why are all of your dates stored as text?

Comment: then how can I use shamsi calender in sql?
this was comfortable for me until this time

Comment: @MPERSIA Ahh I see. That would make things more difficult.

Comment: but this time I'm stuck on this problem